# input verification assignment and displaying if a 2d char array

Tags: c

I am trying to populate a 2d array in C. Everything works out well but the values assigned to the array are not printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h> 

main()
{
    char parkingspace[25][4];
    char CarReg[7], validreg[7];
    int row, position;

    printf( "Enter the car Registration number \n" );
    fgets( CarReg, sizeof( CarReg ), stdin );
    if( isdigit( CarReg[0] )&& isdigit( CarReg[1] ) && (CarReg[2]=='H' ) && ( CarReg[3]=='I' ) && ( CarReg[4]=='R' ) && ( CarReg[5]=='E' ))
    {
        puts( "Valid Registration \n" );
        printf( "==================================================\n\n\n" );
    }
    else
    {   
        puts( "Invalid registration .\n Please put a value of two digits followed by the word HIRE! in caps" );
    }
    printf( "You entered: %s\n", CarReg );
    if( isdigit( CarReg[0] )&& isdigit( CarReg[1] ) && ( CarReg[2]=='H' ) && (CarReg[3]=='I' ) && ( CarReg[4]=='R' ) && ( CarReg[5]=='E' ))
    {
        strcpy(validreg, CarReg);
        printf( "Accepted Car Reg is : %s\n\n\n\n", validreg );
        printf( "==================================================\n\n\n");
    }
    for (row=1; row<26; row++)
    {
        for (position=1;position<5; position++)
        {
            parkingspace[row][position]=validreg;
            printf("parkingspace \t row[%d] position[%d] =[ %c ]\n", row,position,parkingspace[row][position]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the code

Comment: You forgot the code...

Comment: What do you expect it to print, and what does it print

Comment: yes it does print but an empty matrix. .

Comment: IT PRINTS THIS..parkingspace     row[1] position[1] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[1] position[2] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[1] position[3] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[1] position[4] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[2] position[1] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[2] position[2] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[2] position[3] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[2] position[4] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[3] position[1] =[ È ]
parkingspace     row[3] position[2] =[ È ]

Comment: NEW TO THIS SITE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH POSTING

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is that arrays are indexed from zero to size-of-array minus one. So valid indexes for `row` are `0` to `24`, not `1` to `25` like you do.

---

The other problem is that you try to assign a character array to a single character:

```
parkingspace[row][position]=validreg;
```

If you only want the first four characters of `validreg` in `parkingspace[row]` then do e.g. like this for the inner loop:

```
for (position=0; position < 4; position++)
{
    parkingspace[row][position] = validreg[position];
    printf("parkingspace \t row[%d] position[%d] =[ %c ]\n", row, position, parkingspace[row][position]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in line 39

```
parkingspace[row][position]=validreg;
```

should be

```
parkingspace[row][position]=validreg[position];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (row=1; row<26; row++)
{
    for (position=1;position<5; position++)
```

these two lines should be modified as

```
for (row = 0; row < 24; row ++)
{
   for (position =0; position < 3; poisition++)
```

This is because u have declared as char parkingspace[25][4];
Arrays start at index '0' and go till (size - 1)